# Integrate over a set or over the domain of a distribution

Tags: distributions, integral-equations

If Z is a distribution, how do I express “integrate over its domain”?

i.e. in handling symbolic calculation of an expectation of an unknown distribution, you'd normally put a Z under the the integral symbol:

$\int p[f(\theta ,z), z \sim Z] \, dz$

[also] - is there a mathematica.stackexchange meta-site where I can ask, -how do I write the distribution symbol where I've written $z \sim Z$?

Comment: `Expectation[f[z], z \[Distributed] Z]` - to enter the distributed symbol quickly, press the `Escape` key, then type `dist`, then hit the `Escape` key again.

Comment: ah, sorry I meant write the distributed on mathematica.stackexchange.com! Although I see on mathsoverflow they seem happy with the ~-like symbol

Comment: So this is not a Mathematica question ?

Comment: Yes, the title question is a mathematica question. The “(also: … question )” was a “How/where do I ask how to write my question correctly” question

Comment: When you paste in code with the distributed symbol it will show up as `\[Distributed]`.  As far as I know unless you copy code as an image (not recommended at all), there is no option to get the `\[Distributed]`.  However, many other symbols can be displayed as desired from https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a concrete example

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Let

```
f[x_] := Log[x]
```

Example 1

```
distX1 = RayleighDistribution[σ];

m1a = Expectation[f[x], x \[Distributed] distX1]

(* -(EulerGamma/2) + Log[2]/2 + Log[σ] *)
```

Alternatively, use [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) to define the distribution for `f[x]` given the distribution for `x`

```
distF1 = TransformedDistribution[Log[x], x \[Distributed] distX1];

m1a == Mean[distF1]

(* True *)
```

Example 2

```
distX2 = NakagamiDistribution[μ, ω];

m2a = Expectation[f[x], x \[Distributed] distX2]

(* 1/2 (-Log[μ/ω] + PolyGamma[0, μ]) *)
```

Similarly,

```
distF2 = TransformedDistribution[Log[x], x \[Distributed] distX2];

m2a == Mean[distF2]

(* True *)
```

Note that since the [`RayleighDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RayleighDistribution.html) is a special case of the [`NakagamiDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NakagamiDistribution.html), that is,

```
PDF[NakagamiDistribution[1, 2 σ^2], x] == 
 PDF[RayleighDistribution[σ], x]

(* True *)
```

then

```
m1a == (m2a /. {μ -> 1, ω -> 2 σ^2}) // 
 Simplify[#, σ > 0] &

(* True *)
```